# Check the radiobutton from the page fragment

Tags: android

I have a button , I want when I click it goes to the page fragment The radiobutton is checked , If, for example, it was a hello , The word hello is printed on the textview in page MainActivity

page fragment

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.java.frag.BlankFragment">




        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <RadioButton
                android:text="nice to meet you"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <RadioButton
                android:text="welcome"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <RadioButton
                android:text="hello"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:checked="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </RadioGroup>



</LinearLayout>
```

page MainActivity

```
    package com.example.java.frag;

import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView x = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);


    }

    public void changetext(View view) {
        FragmentManager frag = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction tran = frag.beginTransaction();
        BlankFragment s = new BlankFragment();
        tran.replace(R.id.con,s);
        tran.commit();
    }
}
```

How do I do it?

I hope to get an example

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should be very **clear** and **precise** about your query. Next, you should use [EventBus](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/) here. It really comes handy when callbacks between different components are needed. To use EventBus, you should add following dependency in the app's build.gradle:

```
compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
```

Then, you can create a simple [POJO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_Java_object) class to refer a callback or event. In this case, you can create a class like this:

```
class OptionItemEvent {
  private String option;

  public OptionItemEvent(String option){
    this.option = option;
  }

  public String getOption(){
    return option;
  }
}
```

In your BlankFragment.java, you've to make a call to the event in the appropriate listener method, for example in this case:

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int radioButtonId) {
    RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton)view.findViewById(radioButtonId);
    EventBus.getDefault().post(new OptionItemEvent(radioButton.getText().toString()));
}
```

In your MainActivity.java, add the following code:

```
@Override
protected void onResume(){
  super.onResume();
  EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

@Override
protected void onPause(){
  EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
  super.onPause();
}

@Subscribe (threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onOptionItemSelected(OptionItemEvent event){
  //Set the value for your TextView
  x.setText(event.getOption());
}
```

I hope this solves your problem.